# Use FFMpeg to convert dvd's

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to convert files to h265 but they are single files. I'm wondering if it could easily convert a dvd(vob format stuff)? I'd like to avoid first going through handbrake and then transcoding. It should keep the dvd structure and functionally work like handbrake(in the result would be very similar in watching the video). It should be as hassle free as possible since I have several to convert. Ideally I give it the folder path and the params to convert and it does it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8349419/10931455

Comment: @Freddy Concatenation doesn't always work... or maybe it does. Some videos though get screwed up because they are encrypted or have weird things going on. The videos, when converted through concatenation end up skipping around.